# How specify link url in json file to open in same window

Tags: json

It's possible to set url parameter in json to open link in same window?

```
    target: "_parent"
     not work, opens link in new tab/window
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code, that explains how you use json object?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
target: "_self"
```

Answer (score 2):

its working see this code:

```
var headerItems= {
items: [            
         {
            actionId:'logout',
            href:'Logout.jsp',
            label:'Log Out',
            target: "_self"

        }

    ]
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one instead of target and all

**{
name: 'logout',
isLabel: true,
url: 'Logout.jsp',
icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
}**